# Trying to make a language translation app

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, translation

I am trying to make a translation app that can translate a number between 1-30 from english to its german/french counterpart. I think I am somewhat on the right track, ive made the arrays with all the translations, but the problems I am having is I don't know how to correlate the number the user puts in via a prompt, to one of the values in the array, example:

User is prompted for number between 1-30, user is prompted for language French/German = Translation

This is what I am trying to do. Bellow is what I have so far, feel free to nit pick, but bear in mind I am new to Javascript so there is probably a lot wrong.

```
function translate() {
    if (lang = "French") {
    
        console.log(frenchTranslation);
    
    } else {
        console.log(germanTranslation);
    }
};
var x=translate

translate(x)

var number=(Number(prompt ("What is your number? Must be between 1-30")));
var lang=(prompt ("What is your language? Must be 'French' or 'German'. Case Sensitive."));

var frenchTranslation = ["Please enter a number between 1-30", "un","deux","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf",
                         "vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];

var germanTranslation = ["Please enter a number between 1-30","Eins","Zwei","Drei","Vier","Fünf","Sechs","Sieben","Acht","Neun","Zehn","Elf","Zwölf","Dreizehn","Vierzehn","Fünfzehn","Sechzehn","Siebzehn","Achtzehn","Neunzehn",
                         "Zwanzig","Einundzwanzig","Zweiundzwanzig","Dreiundzwanzig","Vierundzwanzig","Fünfundzwanzig","Sechsundzwanzig","Siebenundzwanzig","Achtundzwanzig","Neunundzwanzig","Dreiβig"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, so first of all, you need to add some input validation to know what the user has selected. I recommend storing it somewhere, then you should make sure that it's in the correct range. Just use an if statement to check if the number is >= 0  && <= 30. After that when you're trying to use console.log you need to use array index of the correct number.

Here's my solution, you can improve on it a lot.

```
var frenchTranslation = ["Please enter a number between 1-30", "un","deux","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf",
                         "vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];

var germanTranslation = ["Please enter a number between 1-30","Eins","Zwei","Drei","Vier","Fünf","Sechs","Sieben","Acht","Neun","Zehn","Elf","Zwölf","Dreizehn","Vierzehn","Fünfzehn","Sechzehn","Siebzehn","Achtzehn","Neunzehn",
                         "Zwanzig","Einundzwanzig","Zweiundzwanzig","Dreiundzwanzig","Vierundzwanzig","Fünfundzwanzig","Sechsundzwanzig","Siebenundzwanzig","Achtundzwanzig","Neunundzwanzig","Dreiβig"];

function translate()
{
const yournumber = Number(prompt("Enter your number (1-30)"));
console.log(yournumber);
const language = prompt("Choose a language - German or French");

if(yournumber < 1 || yournumber > 30) {
    alert("Too hard");
}
else {
    if(language === "French") {
        console.log(frenchTranslation[yournumber]);
    }
    if(language === "German") {
        console.log(germanTranslation[yournumber]);
    }
}

}

translate();
```